# How to filter statsd metrics in the DataDog agent?

Tags: datadog

We're using the DataDog agent with some .Net Core micro-services on Linux. We want to send our statsd metrics directly through the DataDog agent but we need to do some filtering before the agent sends the metrics to DataDog.

All I could find was the following: https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/custom_instrumentation/agent_customization/?tab=mongodb

That all appears to be about logging and spans, not metrics.

Is it possible to filter the statsd metrics?

Answer (score 0):

Yes but not if you send the statsd metrics directly to the DataDog agent. You can instead filter the metrics through a proxy service that you configure with the filter settings, e.g. https://github.com/askldjd/statsd-filter-proxy-rs